# threads, proxies and python. And I'm lost

Tags: python, multithreading, proxy

So I have managed to create a script that creates a thread for each line in a file.

These lines contain the following data: Username:Password:Proxy

Though it has the proxy information, I have yet to find out how to use this.

---

**The plan**

The plan here is to schedule certain tasks for each account and execute them through a proxy.

For this particular task I want to automate uploading daily pictures to snapchat.

Now I'm just stuck at the part where I send the information to snapchat using the proxy.

**What I tried**

I tried POSTrequest using the request module, but this did not seem to have any effect.
Even manually setting the proxy with SET HTTP_PROXY in commandline before running the script did not work, it still used my home IP

---

I was wondering if someone could push me in the right direction. Because I'm lost here.

The plan is to manage daily news uploads for stores in my area.
Such as sales etc, and post them to snapchat, so the people that are following them can see them.

Comment: It seems that "upload a picture to snapchat" is the real problem here. Have you done that before? Have you got any information which describes how to do it? I'm willing to bet that Snapchat doesn't really want to support people programmatically sending images through their service (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Part of you is right, I have more the feeling that it's frowned upon, though my reason is not with any bad in mind.
Yes I have successfully uploaded pictures to snapchat from my home IP, it's pretty easy actually. Can I chat with you to show you how, if you are interested in helping ofcourse.